# Going from Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: boot, hard-drive, windows-8, grubrescue

I'm trying to install windows on a computer that before had Ubuntu 13.10. I tried to install windows with a usb. I ended up having to delete my partitions because (ubunutu partition were in the wrong format). I have a main hard drive 475 gb and another one which is 15 gb. Nonetheless, I installed windows on my main hard drive and when it got to the part where the computer was supposed to restart . . . (it restarted but) The computer booted to grub rescue. Saying error:no such device: bb859256-9548-4923-bc43s-599bead4c6f. Entering rescue mode... 
I reinstall windows but it resulted the same. I saw people who have ubuntu and windows dual boot sometimes have the same problem
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Want to install windows on dev/sda2
want to install ubuntu on dev/sda1 
[image]

Comment: boot ubuntu live-disk and then install gparted.Take a screenshot of it and now explain in which partition you are going to install windows and in which partition you are going to install ubuntu from that screenshot.It will be more easy for us to help you.

Comment: is that what you need?

Comment: you can split the /dev/sda2 partition into two partitions.And then you can use one for windows and one for ubuntu.

Comment: okay but i stil have the problem with the grub rescue

Comment: you doesn't face any problems with grub-rescue.Try what i said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Gparted to set aside an empty partition for your Windows.

First, boot Ubuntu using Live USB (Live CD may not work). You can't do partition if you're boot from hard disk.

Next, if you don't have GParted installed in Live USB, get it from Ubuntu store. If you have, open the application.

After that, select the hard disk where your Ubuntu is.

From the disk space, right click then click resize/move to resize your Ubuntu partition.

After resizing is done (could take a long time), you should have an empty partition.

You can then install Windows on the empty partition. Restart the PC and boot with Windows USB.

After Installation of Windows and the computer restart, you may need to upgrade grub.

Hope that helps.
(Note: This method is valid for Windows 7, Vista, XP, 2000, ME, 98, 95. This method have not been tested on Windows 8, as Windows 8 implement UEFI boot option)

Comment: how do i upgrade grub

Comment: Boot to Live USB or Live CD, open terminal, run this command

"sudo update-grub", without the ".

Comment: You can refer to this: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.Uqf3_EOzCfg